# Policy malformed when deploying serverless application

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a lambda function created using the serverless framework that is running into an error when deploying it to a dev environment. Issue seems to be IAM related and isn't a perissions issue so much as AWS says it's a malformed policy. I've included the error message seen in the cloudformation console as well as the entire `serverless.yml` file. Was hoping some could help me fix it, I had it working on another account though have made changes like memory limit and specifying the resource for iam policy. Should add to that, I have confirmed the sqs queue referenced in the iam part does in fact exist and I've tried the exact arn without the `opt:accID` part.

Error message

```
The policy failed legacy parsing (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument;
```

Serverless.yaml file

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  region: us-east-1
  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - ${ssm:/${opt:stage}/securityGroupIds}
    subnetIds:
      - ${ssm:/${opt:stage}/subnetIds}
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: 'Allow'
      Resource: arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:{opt:accID}:influxdb_perf_mon
      Action:
        - 'sqs:*'
  environment:
    tsQueue: https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/${opt:accID}/influxdb_perf_mon

functions:
  perf:
    handler: handler.perf
    memorySize: 128 # in MB
    events:
      - sqs: 
          arn: arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:{opt:accID}:influxdb_perf_mon
          batchSize: 1
```

Cloudformation in S3

```
"IamRoleLambdaExecution": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                  "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                ]
              },
              "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "Policies": [
          {
            "PolicyName": {
              "Fn::Join": [
                "-",
                [
                  "timeseries-lambda",
                  "dev",
                  "lambda"
                ]
              ]
            },
            "PolicyDocument": {
              "Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [
                {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": [
                    "logs:CreateLogStream",
                    "logs:CreateLogGroup"
                  ],
                  "Resource": [
                    {
                      "Fn::Sub": "arn:${AWS::Partition}:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws/lambda/timeseries-lambda-dev*:*"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": [
                    "logs:PutLogEvents"
                  ],
                  "Resource": [
                    {
                      "Fn::Sub": "arn:${AWS::Partition}:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws/lambda/timeseries-lambda-dev*:*:*"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:100525853236:influxdb_perf_mon",
                  "Action": [
                    "sqs:*"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": [
                    "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
                    "sqs:DeleteMessage",
                    "sqs:GetQueueAttributes"
                  ],
                  "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:{opt:accID}:influxdb_perf_mon"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "Path": "/",
        "RoleName": {
          "Fn::Join": [
            "-",
            [
              "timeseries-lambda",
              "dev",
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::Region"
              },
              "lambdaRole"
            ]
          ]
        },
        "ManagedPolicyArns": [
          {
            "Fn::Join": [
              "",
              [
                "arn:",
                {
                  "Ref": "AWS::Partition"
                },
                ":iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole"
              ]
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
```

Comment: Does this fail during deploy stage? If yes, you can go to your S3 bucket, and locate the CloudFormation template that serverless framework genrates. This will enable to inspect full role and may help with the issue.

Comment: @Marcin I added the problematic cloudformation to the OP. I don't know cloudformation so unsure on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that defines the resource for the IAM premissions you have listed has a small typo and is missing the `$`:

`Resource: arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:{opt:accID}:influxdb_perf_mon`

should be

`Resource: arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:${opt:accID}:influxdb_perf_mon`

That may fix your issue

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, I tried that issing `$` and no luck same error message

Answer (score 0):

I **redeployed** your role in my sandabox account. I found that the issue comes from:

```
                {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": [
                    "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
                    "sqs:DeleteMessage",
                    "sqs:GetQueueAttributes"
                  ],
                  "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:{opt:accID}:influxdb_perf_mon"
                  ]
                }
```

Specifically, from `{opt:accID}`. Changing the Resource to (real account number) fixed the issue in my verification:

```
"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:324124214:influxdb_perf_mon"
```

Thus the question is, **where does this policy come from**? Its not listed in your `Serverless.yaml` provided in the question? Are you sure this is the most recent `Serverless.yaml` you use?

Comment: I think that is the most recent one, at least it was the most recent in the s3 dates shown. I took a look at the other places I could be missing a `$` and found one in the events section of the serverless.yaml file. Issue seems resolved now

Comment: @joshk132 Glad to hear. So now the policy I identified is correct? The `event` must have produce the policy.

Comment: Yeah looks like the event was the one creating the policy. Never dug into it before always assumed you had to do that yourself

Comment: @joshk132 Thanks for letting me know. Btw, if either mine or GarethMcCumskey answer was helpful, acceptance of one of them would be appreciated.